# I can't install any apps when I don't have a SD Card in my phone!

Tags: adb, internal-storage, sd-card, installation, internal-sd

I've a problem on my SM-G350. I once set my install location to extrenal via ROM Toolbox Lite. I took out the SD card one day and the other day I tried to install an app and it said that I can't install it to my standard install location, which was fine. I connected it to adb and typed in `pm set install-location 0` I got no error message (I got no message at all), and so I thought it worked, but it didn't. I also entered the command so that everything will be installed on the internal storage but that didn't help either.
What else could I do or what could be the cause of this problem?

Samsung Galaxy Core Plus (SM-G350)
Stock ROM (4.2)

Comment: You missed a dash: `adb shell pm set-install-location 0` it is. See [these posts](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=set-install-location) :)

Comment: Also, try reinserting the SD card. If it works, try using Rom toolbox to reset the install location.

Comment: @Izzy­, yeah, right, but only in the question. After the 5th time I typed it in I always triple checked what I was typing in the command line :D
@DanB­, I installed rom toolbox after a couple of tries but that also didn't work. Reinserting the SD card didn't help. Also a restart didn't work.

Comment: Try checking with `get-install-location` if it took the new setting. If it didn't, try again with root powers.

Comment: It says `0` (automatic).

Comment: Okay, I changed it again with ROM Toolbox and install location was on ´1´ (internal). I tried to install a app and I got the same error message as always. Yes, internal storage is mounted.
I also got it to `2`, but no success either.